# Estimating of variance of dependent normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, independence

Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are independent and identically unobservable variable on $\Omega$. Suppose that $f:\Omega\times\Omega\mapsto \mathbb R$ be unknown function such that we know the value of $f(X_i,X_j)$ for all $i\neq j$. So, we only observe the value of the function without observing $X'$s.

If we assume $f(X_i,X_j)'$s are identically normal with mean $\mu$ and $\sigma^2,$ how will we estimate them? As we know that the observations are not independent, for example $f(X_1,X_2)$ and $f(X_3,X_4)$ are independent but $f(X_1,X_2)$ and $f(X_1,X_3)$ are dependent.

Comment: In your second sentence you call $f$ a function (so $f(X_i,X_j)$ would be some kind of surface). Then you was "it's like we observe the "relation" between $X_i$ and $X_j$", which makes it sound more like your title (some kind of density, perhaps). Then you say $f$ is normal... so $f$ is now a random variable? You post is very unclear. Please try to clarify what it is that's normal, whether $f$ really is a joint density, or a more general function, or a random variable and so on.

Comment: @Glen_b: I've edited there. Here, $f$ is a function. We don't observe $X$ but we observe the value of $f(X_i,X_j)$.

Comment: Okay, if $f$ is a function (let's say $f(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+3y^4}$ for an example), in what sense do you intend that it constitutes a "relation" between the arguments?

Comment: @Glen_b: In your case, the relation between between the arguments is $\sqrt {x^2+3y^4}$ itself. Another example is that we only observe the sum for every pair $(X_i,X_j).$ In this case, $f(x,y)=x+y$

Comment: The expression $\sqrt{x^2+3y^4}$ (or $x+y$ for that matter) isn't really a relation in the usual (mathematical) sense because it doesn't *relate* $x$ and $y$. *Level sets* of $\sqrt{x^2+3y^4}$ could be construed as a relation, perhaps, but I don't expect that's what you're trying to get at. Please clarify in what sense some expression like $x+y$ could be considered to *relate* $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @Glen_b: Thanks for your time. I've clarified my question there.

Comment: I'm sorry I really have no sense of what you want.

Comment: Sometimes it helps to write your actual use-case rather than general statements. Is your f the sum of two random variables? Are you "selecting with replacement" from a set, two at a time ad observing their sums?

Comment: @RohitChatterjee: Yes, something like that. But my $f$ is unknown function.

Comment: @Glen_b: Is my question still not clear?

Comment: I am sorry, I really don't follow your question.