# Estimation based on observing sum of two variables

Tags: normal-distribution, estimation, independence

Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are i.i.d normal $N(\mu,\sigma^2).$ Suppose that we only observe
$$
X_1+X_2,\dots,X_1+X_n,\dots,X_{n-1}+X_n,
$$
i.e, $X_i+X_j$ for all $i<j.$

I wish to find the best estimator $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ based on the above abservation. How will I do that?

As we know that if we observe $X$'s then it is easy to estimate $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$. However, since we observe ${n\choose 2}-$identically variables $X_i+X_j$ that are not independent one to the each other, then it would become more difficult. Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you have in mind any parctical situation leading to data of that kind?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen: no, I don't. It is actually a special case of my research

Comment: This seems to be a (very) special case of your [previous question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118541/estimating-of-variance-of-dependent-normal-distribution). If this is the *only* case in which you are interested, should we close the previous question?

Comment: Note that one very straightforward way to obtain a good estimator of $\mu$ is to use an obvious one--such as $X_1+X_2$--and apply the [Rao-Blackwell process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rao%E2%80%93Blackwell_theorem). Whether that is "best" depends on unstated assumptions such as your loss function and any restrictions you might want to place on the estimator, such as being linear or unbiased.

Comment: @whuber: Yes, indeed. It is a special case of my previous question. I asked it because I wanna get an illustration when $f(x,y)=x+y$

Answer (score 3):

This is a usual linear model. You have $$\mathbf{Y}=(X_1+X_2,\ldots)'=\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{1}\mu) +\mathbf{\epsilon},$$ where $\mathbf{\epsilon} = (\epsilon_1,\ldots,\epsilon_n)=(X_i-\mu)_{i=1,\ldots ,n}$ is the error term. $\mathbf{A}$ is a $n \times {n \choose 2}$-matrix with twice the entry 1 in each row.

The rest is done by linear model estimation. You may try $\mu=(A'A)^{-}A'Y$, where $^-$ denotes a generalized inverse. Check if $(A'A)^-(A'A)=1$, then this is a BLUE. See Rao (1962).

Another approach for your special case: Clearly $E(Y_k)=2\mu$ and $Var(Y_k)=2\sigma^2$.

Comment: And, I guess, $A$ has full rank, so you can recover the $$'s exactly.  But even if that guess is wrong, you can do as above.

Comment: @Horst: Thanks for your help. Can we still recover $X$ if we observe $X_iX_j$ or $X_i^2+X_j$?

Comment: @Jlamprong: So you have a mapping of the vector $X$ to a long vector with the entries $X_i X_j$ and $X_i^2 + X_j$ and ask if this mapping is injective?

Comment: @HorstGrünbusch: Isn't like $X_i+X_j?$